# Segfault when reading from update linked list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, hashtable

So I'm working on an implementation of a hash table. I'm not very experienced with C and pointers and getting a bit stuck.

I've got hashtable definition that looks like this:

```
typedef struct KVnode {
  int kv[2];
  struct KVnode *next;
} KVnode;

typedef struct hashtable {
  int size;     // size of hash table
  int entries;  // number of slots allocated in table
  KVnode *table;   /* pointer to table. Each entry will point to linked list
                      of key-value nodes */
} hashtable;
```

Where the hash table struct contains a table of KVnode pointers. The KVnodes are essentially a linked list to store collisions.

My implementation of put looks like this:

```
void put(hashtable* ht, keyType key, valType value){
  int index = hash_key(key, ht->size);

  KVnode *new_node = malloc( sizeof(KVnode) );
  new_node->kv[0] = key;
  new_node->kv[1] = value;
  new_node->next = NULL;

  printf("Inserting at index: %i, key:%i, val:%i \n", index, key, value);

  // If next val is 0, we can set the first node to key-value
  if( ht->table[index].next == 0)
    ht->table[index] = *new_node;
  else{ // find last node in linked list and append new_node
      KVnode cn = ht->table[index];
      while( cn.next != NULL )
        cn = *cn.next;
      cn.next = new_node;
  }
}
```

And here the overall code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 503

typedef struct KVnode {
  int kv[2];
  struct KVnode *next;
} KVnode;

typedef struct hashtable {
  int size;     // size of hash table
  int entries;  // number of slots allocated in table
  KVnode *table;   /* pointer to table. Each entry will point to linked list
                      of key-value nodes */
} hashtable;

typedef int keyType;
typedef int valType;

void init(hashtable**);
int hash_key(keyType key, int size);
void put(hashtable* ht, keyType key, valType value);

void init(hashtable** ht) {
    *ht = (hashtable *) malloc( sizeof(hashtable) );
    if(*ht == NULL){
      printf( "Error: Unable to allocate memory for hashtable" );
      exit(1);
    }
    else{
      (*ht)->entries = 0;
      (*ht)->size = SIZE;
      (*ht)->table = calloc((*ht)->size , sizeof(KVnode *));
    }
}

int hash_key(keyType key, int size){
    return key % size;
}

void put(hashtable* ht, keyType key, valType value){
  int index = hash_key(key, ht->size);

  KVnode *new_node = malloc( sizeof(KVnode) );
  new_node->kv[0] = key;
  new_node->kv[1] = value;
  new_node->next = NULL;

  printf("Inserting at index: %i, key:%i, val:%i \n", index, key, value);

  // If next val is 0, we can set the first node to key-value
  if( ht->table[index].next == 0)
    ht->table[index] = *new_node;
  else{ // find last node in linked list and append new_node
      KVnode cn = ht->table[index];
      while( cn.next != NULL )
        cn = *cn.next;
      cn.next = new_node;
  }
}

int main(){

  hashtable *t = NULL;
  init(&t);

  put(t, 225, 100);
  put(t, 55555, 100);

  printf("node at 255, k:%i, v:%i\n", t->table[225].kv[0],t->table[225].kv[1] );
  printf("node at 255, 2nd node, k:%i, v:%i\n",
         t->table[225].next->kv[0],t->table[225].next->kv[1] );


  free(t);
}
```

The program compiles fine but at runtime i get at segfault. Here's the output:

```
ds-MacBook-Pro:project0 d$ ./ll
Inserting at index: 225, key:225, val:100
Inserting at index: 225, key:55555, val:100
node at 255, k:55555, v:100
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I can't figure out if the issue is my print statement or if I'm actually not appending the linked list correctly in put.

Comment: Step #1) spend some time learning how to use a debugger.  Really.  It is just as important as learning the language.

Comment: `(*ht)->table = calloc((*ht)->size , sizeof(KVnode *));` : `sizeof(KVnode *)` --> `sizeof(KVnode)`

Comment: Be careful, `free(t);` may not free all allocated memory causing memory leaks.

Comment: as @BLUEPIXY points out, you don't allocate enough space for the table.  As an experiment. print out the values of both: `sizeof(KVnode *)` and `sizeof(KVnode)`

Comment: `t->table[225].next->kv[0],t->table[225].next->kv[1]` : `t->table[225].next` is `NULL`. Because `KVnode cn = ht->table[index];`

Comment: I think one of the problems I'm running into put is I don't know how to check if the first node is initialized.

It looks like the statement below always resolves to true so the else block is never executed. 
// If next val is 0, we can set the first node to key-value
  if( ht->table[index].next == 0)
    ht->table[index] = *new_node;
  
how would I check if the first node is null? Originally I used malloc to initialize the table in intit() function but that didn't give me a reliable way to check if the nodes in the table were initialized.

Comment: previous my comment : Because `KVnode cn = ht->table[index];` --> Because `if( ht->table[index].next == 0)` (and `KVnode cn = ht->table[index];`)

Comment: _how would I check if the first node is null?_ option (1) `KVnode *table;` --> `KVnode **table;` option (2) Use `ht->table[index]` as dummy head.

Comment: make friends with valgrind